# Can´t use Label in new custom Procedure

Tags: label, pascal, lazarus

I am trying to create a retro text based game in style of Dungeons and Dragons. I encountered problem when I try to display number in Label. It seems that the procedure can´t find the Label from list. I always get:  *Error: Identifier not found "Label6"*

Code:

```
procedure health;
var hp: integer;
begin
  hp:=100;
  Label6.Caption:= inttostr(hp);
end;
```

Comment: Almost certainly `Label6` is a member of a form class, but `health` is a not method of this class (indeed, it is not a method at all). So you either need to make `health` a method of the same class which contains `Label6`, or you need a reference to the instance of the class you want to work with.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand thank you for answering, I can´t find anything about making my procedure a method. Do you have any link or advice?

Comment: I don't know FreePascal, but Delphi has [good documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Methods_(Delphi)). Basically you need to add `procedure health;` to your form class's declaration (`private` or `public` or whatever is appropriate), and then write `procedure TForm1.health;` in the implementation section, assuming the form class is named `TForm1`. (Or you can do it the wrong way just to learn: write `Form1.Label6.Caption := ` instead, assuming there is a global variable with a default instance of the class.)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Thanks a lot! It worked! I did mistake when adding form1 in front of health. Just a small detail and so much lost time. Again thx